# Bold Author names with elsarticle-num bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle

I want to have bold author name whenever it appear in references of latex like as follows:

[1] **R. A. Khan**, Y. Luo, F.-X. Wu, Machine learning based liver disease diagnosis: A systematic
review, Neurocomputing 468 (2022) 492–509. doi:10.1016/j.neucom.2021.08.138. 1

[2] Z. Baig, N. Abu-Omar, **R. A. Khan**, C. Verdiales, R. Frehlick, J. Shaw, F.-X. Wu, Y. Luo,
Prognosticating outcome in pancreatic head cancer with the use of a machine learning algorithm,
Technology in cancer research & treatment 20 (2021). doi:10.1177/15330338211050767.

[3] **R. A. Khan**, Y. Luo, F.-X. Wu, RMS-UNet: Residual multi-scale UNet for liver and lesion
segmentation, Artificial Intelligence in Medicine 124 (2022) 102–231. doi:10.1016/j.artmed.
2021.102231.

[4] **R. A. Khan**, Y. Luo, F.-X. Wu, Liver cancer diagnosis based on CT scan enhanced images with
multi-level generative adversarial network, Cancers (2022). 1

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you considered opening the .bbl file in a text editor and performing a search for the string `R. A. Khan` and replacing these strings globally with `\textbf{R. A. Khan}`? Of course, do that only when you're virtually done with the paper and won't have to re-run BibTeX.

Comment: I tried to do that in the bib file but it wouldn't work instead it just messed up format style.

Comment: I was looking for something to define some command globally in the TEX file that bolds the text if found in references

Comment: I wrote "bbl file", *not* "bib file".

Comment: I find the bbl file, but should I download and edit it or is there any other way around to edit it online in overleaf? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "downloading" the bbl file that's already in your Overleaf directory. I'd suggest you just open it with Overleaf's built-in editor.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution would be to use the `\textbf{}` command directly in your .bib file entries.

You can create a copy of your .bib database and use the replace command to create the entries with that specific name in bold.

See the example below.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[final,10pt]{elsarticle}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Enable Palatino (I am using pdfLaTeX)
\usepackage{hyperref} % Setup hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{same}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@PhdThesis{phd:Will,
  author    = {\textbf{Fonseca, William {\relax D'A}ndrea}},
  title     = {{B}eamforming {C}onsidering {A}coustic {D}iffraction over {C}ylindrical {S}urfaces},
  type      = {{P}h{D} {D}issertation},
  address   = {Florianópolis, SC, Brazil},
  school    = {Graduate Program in Mechanical Engineering, Federal University of Santa Catarina},
  year      = {2013},
  isbn      = {978-8591677405},
  url ={https://repositorio.ufsc.br/xmlui/handle/123456789/107608} 
}
@Article{jasa:2022eac,
  author  = {\textbf{Fonseca, William {\relax D'A}ndrea} and Brandão, Eric and Mareze, Paulo Henrique and Viviane Suzey Melo and Roberto A. Tenenbaum and Christian Santos and Dinara Xavier Paixão},
  title   = {{A}coustical {E}ngineering: a complete academic undergraduate program in {B}razil},
  doi     = {10.1121/10.0013570},
  issn    = {0001-4966, 1520-8524},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {1180--1191},
  volume  = {152},
  journal = {The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
  year    = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Bib Options: elsarticle uses natbib
\biboptions{sort&compress,square}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Test Section}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Reference with several names: \cite{jasa:2022eac}
    \item Reference with one name: \cite{phd:Will}
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{example.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]